# How to compare elements in int array to a integer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, comparison, int

I want to compare an array containing int values to a number

example [1,2,30,1,40,200,10,500] < 500 meaning if array contains elements less than 500.

How can i do dis?

Thank alot in advance

I did this bt it say invalid opernd:

```
if ([placeName count])
{
    for (int i =0; i < [placeName count]; i++) 
    {
        NSArray *sortedArray=[placeName sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:NULL];
        self.placeName = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];

        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSDecimalNumber *Distance = [tempArray objectForKey:@"distance"];

        NSMutableArray *intDistanse=[Distance intValue];
        DLog(@"Distance%d", intDistanse);

        NSMutableArray *intDistanse=[Distance intValue];
        DLog(@"Distance%d", intDistanse);

        for(int j = 0; j < [intDistanse count]; j++)
        {
             if ( intDistanse[j] < 500 ) //here its says error
             {

                DLog(@"success");

             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just loop through the length of the array comparing each element with the given number...beginner's problem!

Comment: Yup beginners problem :)

Comment: please check my question i edited it! thnx

Comment: you can not declare integer i again! change it!!!

Comment: error: invalid operands to binary < (have 'struct NSMutableArray' and 'int')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did find a solution to it type casting:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
        //DLog(@"sortedArray%@", sortedArray);8=
        NSNumber *DistanceNum = [tempArray objectForKey:@"distance"];
        NSLog(@"distance%@:::",DistanceNum);
        NSInteger intDistance = (int)[DistanceNum floatValue];

        if(intDistance<500)
        {
            NSLog(@"h:)");
            NSString *notifications =@"Yes";
            [[AppHelper mDataManager] setObject:notifications forKey:@"notifications"]; 

            NSLog(@"notifications:%@",notifications);
            RemindMeViewController *object = [[RemindMeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RemindMeViewController" bundle:nil];
            //  RemindMeViewController *object=[[RemindMeViewController alloc]initWithNibName];

            NSLog(@"notifications set");
            [object scheduleNotification];
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

What kind of an array?  NSArray or language array?

Easiest way is a loop.    Without knowing the type of the array, this is pseudo code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    if ( array[i] < 500 )
         .... got an element less than 500 ....
```

---

The code doesn't really make sense:

- that code should be generating a ton of compiler warnings;  every warning indicates a bug that should be fixed.   Also, try "Build and Analyze".
- you are sorting an array every time through the loop;  waste of resources and doesn't make sense
- everything being typed as NSMutableArray* doesn't make sense;  do you really have an array of arrays of arrays?
- ... calling objectForKey: on anything but an NSDictionary doesn't work
- intValue returns an (int), not an NSMutableArray*
- if intDistance is an (int), then it should just be ( intDistance < 500 )

Overall, I would suggest you step back and review the [Objective-C language guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/introduction/introobjectivec.html) and a bunch of working examples.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you *loop* over each element in the array, checking if each element is less than 500.

For example:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i < THE_SIZE_OF_THE_ARRAY; ++i)
{
  if (array[i] < 500)
  {
    /* Do something */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see whether there is at least one item that matches your condition:

```
bool found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(example)/sizeof(example[0]); ++i)
{
    if(example[i] < 500)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

And if you want to check whether all items match your condition:

```
bool found = true;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(example)/sizeof(example[0]); ++i)
{
    if(example[i] >= 500)
    {
        found = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this very easily by just implementing the observer to compare. Following is just an example to implement the custom observer to compare

```
@implementation NSArray (KVO)

- (void)addObserver:(NSObject *)observer toObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options context:(void *)context
{
    NSUInteger idx=[indexes firstIndex];
    while(idx!=NSNotFound)
    {
        [[self objectAtIndex:idx] addObserver:observer
                                   forKeyPath:keyPath
                                      options:options
                                      context:context];
        idx=[indexes indexGreaterThanIndex:idx];
    }
}

- (void)removeObserver:(NSObject *)observer fromObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    NSUInteger idx=[indexes firstIndex];
    while(idx!=NSNotFound)
    {
        [[self objectAtIndex:idx] removeObserver:observer
                                      forKeyPath:keyPath];
        idx=[indexes indexGreaterThanIndex:idx];
    }
}

-(void)addObserver:(id)observer forKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options context:(void*)context;
{
    if([isa instanceMethodForSelector:_cmd]==[NSArray instanceMethodForSelector:_cmd])
        NSRaiseException(NSInvalidArgumentException,self,_cmd,@"not supported for key path %@ (observer was %@)", keyPath, observer);
    else
        [super addObserver:observer
                forKeyPath:keyPath
                   options:options
                   context:context];
}

-(void)removeObserver:(id)observer forKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath;
{
    if([isa instanceMethodForSelector:_cmd]==[NSArray instanceMethodForSelector:_cmd])
        NSRaiseException(NSInvalidArgumentException,self,_cmd,@"not supported for key path %@ (observer was %@)", keyPath, observer);   
    else
        [super removeObserver:observer
                   forKeyPath:keyPath];
}
@end
```